# What is the difference between a SmtpException and a SmtpFailedRecipientException

Tags: c#, exception, smtp

I have been looking at the MSDN documentation and I cannot seem to work out what the difference is:

[**SmtpException Class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mail.SmtpException(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents the exception that is thrown when the SmtpClient is not able to complete a Send or SendAsync operation.

[**SmtpFailedRecipientException**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents the exception that is thrown when the SmtpClient is not able to complete a Send or SendAsync operation to a particular recipient.

I can't find any information in the documentation to what "operation to a particular recipient" actually means.

**Aside**

The reason I ask is because I am trying to catch certain exceptions in my client application and execute different methods accordingly.

***For Example:***

- If server is down I would like to leave the file where it is
- If send address is invalid I would like to move the file to "Failed" folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source for SmtpClient.cs indicates that SmtpException is used for exceptions trying to get to the point of sending the message. SmtpFailedRecipientException is for an error reaching the client (but everything on the server worked fine).